# Crop thumbnail image to square in Codeigniter

Tags: php, css, image, codeigniter

I am uploading some images to my webpage and would like their thumbnails to be squares cropped from the centre. I am using Codeigniter and gd2.

Here is my code so far:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config['source_image'] = $this->userlibrary->picturesdir . $newfilename;
$config['new_image'] = $this->userlibrary->thumbsdir;
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']= 150;
$config['height']= 150;
```

The images are scaled nicely but they maintain their aspect ratio and only their width OR height gets set to 150, they are not cropped.
Setting `maintain_ratio` will still not crop the image but skew it instead.

How could I do this?

Comment: See if this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002244/crop-resize-image-function-using-gd-library/28008400#28008400

Comment: You could crop the original image to square and then resize it.

Answer (score 2):

Super late response, but I came across this post when I was looking for the same thing. Thought I'd share the solution I went with for anyone else searching for the same.

```
        $config['source_image'] = 'path/to/image';

        //Find smallest dimension
        $imageSize = $this->image_lib->get_image_properties($config['source_image'], TRUE);
        $newSize = min($imageSize);

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['width'] = $newSize;
        $config['height'] = $newSize;
        $config['y_axis'] = ($imageSize['height'] - $newSize) / 2;
        $config['x_axis'] = ($imageSize['width'] - $newSize) / 2;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->image_lib->crop())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set config for img library
$config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin/';
$config['source_image'] = $filePath . $fileOldName;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = false;

//Set cropping for y or x axis, depending on image orientation
if ($fileData['image_width'] > $fileData['image_height']) {
    $config['width'] = $fileData['image_height'];
    $config['height'] = $fileData['image_height'];
    $config['x_axis'] = (($fileData['image_width'] / 2) - ($config['width'] / 2));
}
else {
    $config['height'] = $fileData['image_width'];
    $config['width'] = $fileData['image_width'];
    $config['y_axis'] = (($fileData['image_height'] / 2) - ($config['height'] / 2));
}

//Load image library and crop
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
if ($this->image_lib->crop()) {
    $error = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}

//Clear image library settings so we can do some more image 
//manipulations if we have to
$this->image_lib->clear();
unset($config);
```

Source:
https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-7286.html